# Quotient by finite subgroups are biholomorphic.

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, complex-geometry, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a complex manifold and let $G$ and $H$ be two finite subgroups of its automorphism group $Aut(X)$. Suppose we are given that $X/G$ and $X/H$ are bi-holomorphic complex manifolds. What can we say about $G$ and $H$?

Is it the case that $G$ and $H$ have to be isomorphic as subgroups?

Comment: Does your formulation implicitly assume that $G,H$ act nicely enough on $X$ for $X/G, X/H$ to be complex manifolds as well ?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Also since the subgroups are finite, the action is properly discontinuous (although this does not guarantee that the quotients are complex manifolds).

Comment: Are you saying if $X$ is simply connected then the fundamental group of $X/G$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: We do not know if the action is free. In this case the fundamental group is given by $G/N$ where $N$ is a normal subgroup generated by those elements of $G$ that have fixed points. Also an example: take $X$ the $n$-fold Cartesian product of the unit disc in the complex plane. And $G$ to be the permutation group on $n$-symbols, then $X/G$, the symmetric product of the unit disc is simply connected complex manifold.

Answer (score 1):

The isomorphism $G\cong H$ is false already when $X=CP^1$. For every finite group $F$ of biholomorphic automorphisms of $X=CP^1$, $X/F\cong X$ (since $X/F$ is a genus zero compact connected Riemann surface).

Even if you assume that actions are free the claim is false, but to construct examples you consider an elliptic curve $X$ instead of $CP^1$. (One can find examples with $G=\{1\}$ and $H\cong Z/2\times Z/2$.)